# Query to check Max data in Mysql Database not correct

Tags: mysql

I have a table `reg` in my DB:

```
register_id
-----------
REG-3
REG-5
REG-9
REG-10
```

When I query select max this result: **REG-9** (this is wrong - **REG-10** is the correct answer).

This is my query:

```
SELECT max(register_id) AS maxdata
FROM reg
```

Help Me Thank's

Comment: Store the string and the int separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  max(CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(register_id,'-',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER))
FROM reg
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce23d/17)**

```
SELECT  register_id
FROM reg
group by register_id
having max(CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(register_id,'-',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER))
limit 1
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce23d/22)**

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int)) AS maxdata FROM reg' at line 1

Comment: @MuhamadRidwansyah:- Please check the updated answer!

Comment: @MuhamadRidwansyah:- Updated that!

Comment: but i try in MYSQL Localhost and MYSQL Server this result show REG-3